# Removing event handlers of children

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, unbind

I am trying to unbind event handlers (click) from all a-tags, and somehow it is not working. Do you guys know why?

```
// Remove eventhandlers
    row.find('a').each(function(){
        $(this).unbind('click');
        alert($(this).attr("onClick"));
    });
```

It will always output the current onClick function.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `.unbind()` only removes handlers assigned and maintained by jQuery. Your inline handlers are not affected.

If you want to remove an inline attribute, use `removeAttr()`.

```
row.find('a').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('onClick');
    alert($(this).attr("onClick"));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').unbind('click');
```

or

```
$('a').each(function() {
  return false;
});
```